# probabily on tetrahedron

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given a tetrahedron with the numbers $1,2,3,4$ on its faces.
The tetrahedron is launch $K$ times.
Let $x_{n}$ be the number that shown on the $n$-th launch. 
The probability for each face, is the number that shown on the face divided by the sum of 
the numbers on the faces. i.e: $p(x_{i}=3)=\frac{3}{1+2+3+4}$.

1. if we draw a probability tree, and the branches add up to 65,536 so $k$?
2. given the situation: in 8 launches,the probability getting twice the number 1 and six times the number 3, how many branches fit the situation?
3. what's the probability getting a number of 8 digits which has more prime numbers than not prime?

I would appreciate any help!

**EDIT**: i did make an effort. i tried to use probability mass function but didn't get anything useful. and in question (3) i fixed from 9 digits to **8** digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  1) there are four branches if $K=1$.  How many if $K=2?$

2) this is combinatorics-no probability needed.

3) presumably this is for nine launches.  Note that there are two primes, so you need at least $5 \ \ 2$'s or $3$'s  There is a nice symmetry that makes this one easy.  With the correction to 8 throws, the symmetry is not so nice.

Comment: 1) is it $20$?, 2) how? i can't get those branches. thanks for you comment.

Comment: oh im sorry now i see it's a 8 digit number.

Comment: @user64370:  no, it is not 20.  For each branch of the one level tree, there are four of the two level tree, which makes $16$.  You don't count the first level branches separately on the two level tree.  For 2, each branch is a specific list of throws.  For the two level tree they would be $\{11,12,13,\ldots 44\}$.  You are being asked to count how many branches of the eight level tree have $2\ 1$'s and $6 \ 3$'s, not the probability of getting one.

Comment: in that case is it $28$? but i still don't get how to do (1).

Comment: @user64370:  that is correct for item 2.  For 1, the set I showed in the last comment is the set of branches for the two level tree.  Now think of extending it one more level.  You again multiply the number of elements by $4$ because you can extend each branch with any of $1,2,3,4$  That gives you how many?  Can you see the pattern and find a formula for the number of branches of length $K$?

Comment: ill try to draw but i can't see for now the pattern.

Comment: @user64370:  each time you throw the die there are four possibilities.  So for $1$ throw there are $4$, for $2$ throws  there are $4 \cdot 4$, for $3,\ \ 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4=4^3$, for $k,\ \ 4^k$

Comment: oh i misread it! of course. so it should be $k=8$.

Comment: about (3), how symmetry can make it easy?

Comment: For part 3, what is the probability of a prime on one throw?  When there were 9 throws you just needed a majority to be prime.  Now with 8 there is the chance of a tie.

Comment: i got $0.36328125$. i computed by Probability mass function for $p=(x=0,1,2,3)$

Comment: Good.  Because of the symmetry, you could argue that the chance of 0-3 primes is the same as 5-8 primes, which is $\frac 12(1-$probability of 4 primes$)$ which might be easier.  When there were 9 rounds, you could say it was $\frac 12$ without any calculation from the symmetry.

Comment: nice! got it, thanks a lot.